# Etymology of the word 'choreography'

Tags: etymology

So here in India, in context of movies, choreography relates to direction of dance sequences, but I'm given to understand that in the west, the word is used to describe direction of fight sequences.

Since dancing and fighting are entirely different things, (albeit they both involve body movements,) I was wondering what *choreo* meant. I tried to consult [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/choreography), but there, the word origin directs me to [chorea](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/chorea), which is defined as a disease of the CNS. I fail to see the relevance.

Additionally, -graphy should mean something related to writing. But neither of these involve a lot of writing. Again, I fail to see the relevance.

Does anyone know the original meaning of this word, and how it came to mean what it does today?

Comment: In the West it can mean either.

Comment: Choreography: 1789, from French chorégraphie, coined from Latinized form of Greek khoreia "dance" (see chorus) + graphein "to write" (see -graphy). http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=choreography

Comment: Well, you link to "chorea" includes a hint in the right direction: it is also called St. Vitus's dance

Comment: could you tell where did you find that it is used to describe direction of fight sequences

Comment: @VeronicaDiamond That’s a very common usage; compare the first paragraph in the [Wikipedia article on _Stage combat_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stage_combat).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet : Thanks, Janus. I went to the link you provided . It very clearly mentions Fight Choreography. I believe there's the answer to this question. Choreography is referred to normal dance and fight choreography is related to stage fights/combats.

Comment: @VeronicaDiamond If you’re being specific, _dance choreography_ and _fight choreography_ are preferable (and both are frequently used terms); if it’s obvious which one you’re talking about, _choreography_ on its own works fine for either.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet :what's your answer?

Comment: The use of "choreography" to refer to movie fight scenes is relatively recent, and the use is somewhat ironic.  Any supposedly "natural" sequence which was in fact planned in advance is said (in this ironic sense) to be "choreographed", whether it be a fight sequence (the term's been used in reference to professional wrestling matches for decades) or some sort of "spontaneous" political rally.  The ironic/metaphoric reference is always back to "choreography" as used in dance.

Comment: Downvoters, a little help... what didn't you like about the question?

Comment: @Josh61: +1. If that was an answer I'd have +1'd it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am taking it down mainly from my favorite wikipedia and M-W.

Choreography is the art or practice of designing sequences of movements of physical bodies (or their depictions) in which motion, form, or both are specified.

In dance, choreography is defined as the art of symbolically representing dancing.
It is derived from French chorégraphie, from Greek choreia + French - graphie -graphy.

Graphy is a way of writing or showing something, hence we can related it to symbolically representing something , in this case : body movements.

It will depend on the context in which you are talking about the word.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific as to how the greek choreia relates to dance?

Comment: How does *choreia* relate to dance? A [*khoros*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=chorus&allowed_in_frame=0), was a group of actors in Greek plays who sang and danced. A [khoreia](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chorea) was an ancient Greek circle dance.

Answer (score 2):

Both contexts you refer to (dancing and stage/movie fighting) involve planning movements of one or more persons in entertainment/art/amusement. Thus, choreographers - people who plan out the movements of dancers/actors are involved in both contexts.  Staged fights are essentially a form of performance art, just like dancing.

"Choreography" is generally not used in the context of real fights - contests of skill to determine dominance.

Comment: How does this answer my question?

Comment: The etymology you requested is in the comments and you can look it up. The answer explains why the word is used in the context you described in your comments.

Comment: Saw Josh61's comment. Thanks. But it appears that etymologically choreography referred specifically to dance, not generic body movement. I guess it was at a later time that the term was used for fight movements too. Was hoping someone will shed some more light.

Comment: In terms of WHY -graphy is used, it is because dance/fight directions are a composed sequence, that is capable of being written down and very often is. The word was created at a time when dance steps were generally written down in some way (diagrams and descriptions usually).

Comment: when and how the word choreography was accepted in application to fight sequences is an interesting historical question. I don't know the answer. I hope someone knows and responds.

Comment: Too bad. +1 for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

According to Etymonline:

[Choreography](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=choreography) (n.):

> - 1789, from French chorégraphie, coined from Latinized form of Greek khoreia "dance" (see chorus) + graphein "to write" (see -graphy). Related: Choreographic.

[Chorus:](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=chorus&allowed_in_frame=0)

> - **1560s, from Latin chorus "a dance in a circle, the persons singing and dancing, the chorus of a tragedy," from Greek khoros "band of dancers or singers, dance, dancing ground,"** perhaps from PIE *gher- "to grasp, enclose," if the original sense of the Greek word is "enclosed dancing floor."
> - Extension from dance to voice is because Attic drama arose from tales inserted in the intervals of the dance. In Attic tragedy, the khoros (of 12 or 15 (tragic) or 24 (comedic) persons) gave expression, between the acts, to the moral and religious sentiments evoked by the actions of the play.

[-graphy](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-graphy&allowed_in_frame=0):

> - **word-forming element meaning "process of writing or recording" or "a writing, recording, or description" (in modern use especially in forming names of descriptive sciences),** from French or German -graphie, from Greek -graphia "description of," used in abstract nouns from graphein "write, express by written characters," earlier "to draw, represent by lines drawn," originally "to scrape, scratch" (on clay tablets with a stylus), from PIE root *gerbh- "to scratch, carve" (see carve).

According to [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dance%20choreography%2Cfight%20choreography&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdance%20choreography%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfight%20choreography%3B%2Cc0) the expression *fight choreography* has been used from the mid '60s, probably in relation to movies popular at that time.

Comment: Thanks. This was helpful. +1. Could you possibly know when did choreography come to be associated with fighting?

Comment: @Tushar -       As shown   in the etymologic reference the tern derives   from two terms meaning *dance and writing'. Choreography  is not specifically linked to fighting in a belligerent sense, but only to any representation of it for entertainment purposes.

Comment: Yeah. I got that. But origin of choreo in that sense is also unclear.

Comment: The root word is *chorus* not *choreo*. You are probably misunderstanding this point.

Comment: "there is no hint at fighting in its origin". That's what I'm getting at. No hint of fighting in origin (etymology). But at some point people started to use it to mean fighting (representational/directed; not belligerent). When did they do so and why? (The 'origin' of this usage (not etymological))

Comment: I'm not misunderstanding. My point is chorus/choreo/khoreia/khoros does not indicate to (representational) fighting. So when did it begin to mean that.

Comment: That's better. Please edit your answer and include the ngram link to make it more helpful.

Comment: @Tushar - Choreography, in the US and, I'm confident, the British Isles, does *not* mean fighting.  It refers to pre-planning a performance.  Its relation to fighting is no more than "red" would have if most fighters wore red underwear.

Answer (score -5):

Its derived from the greek word

> Khoros

which means Chorus, as in, in unison. So it defines how a group of people dance together, perhaps?

And as for **-graphy**, it could have something to do with the fact that,initially, dance sequences and moves were written down?

Comment: I am not quite sure how you thought you can start your answer with "It is derived from" as if you are stating a provable fact, but then the next sentence ends with "perhaps". Answers on this site should include facts (and references), not guesses.

Comment: It IS derived from the said word. No one's guessing there, I was stating a provable fact. The NEXT sentence ended with "perhaps", not the first one.  Pretty straightforward thinking, actually. Having a rough day?

Comment: That is not the etymology.